# How to fetch attributes from XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.08.xsd"
 xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd"
 xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
 <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
 <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
     <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO_R">
         <xn:SubNetwork id="MKT_9364">
             <xn:MeContext id="936426_SEYMOUR">
             </xn:MeContext>
         </xn:SubNetwork>
     </xn:SubNetwork>
 </configData>
 <fileFooter dateTime="2017-05-08T10:15:53Z"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

I want to grab all the attributes from the file. I can get `@doc.at('fileHeader')['vendorName']` but I am not getting the expected result `ONRM_ROOT_MO_R` for the second `puts` statement.

Here is my Ruby code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'xmlsimple'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'ap'


@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("seymour.xml"))
puts @doc.at('fileHeader')['vendorName']
puts @doc.at('xn:SubNetwork')['id']
```

The output is:

```
 Ericsson
./bulk_cm_parse.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass 
(NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing to make the problem more clear.

Comment: It's not necessary to thank us. Also, comments aren't for thanking people. Upvotes and selecting answers do that. See the last paragraph in http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your document has namespaces, so you have to take those into account, plus your selector was wrong:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.08.xsd"
xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd"
xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
<fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
<configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
    <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO_R">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="MKT_9364">
            <xn:MeContext id="936426_SEYMOUR">
            </xn:MeContext>
        </xn:SubNetwork>
    </xn:SubNetwork>
</configData>
<fileFooter dateTime="2017-05-08T10:15:53Z"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
EOT

namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces
doc.at('xn|SubNetwork', namespaces)['id'] # => "ONRM_ROOT_MO_R"
```

`at`, like `search` tries to figure out whether you're using a CSS selector or XPath. Your selector didn't have the normal XPath earmarks, so it assumed you meant CSS, but then the namespace wasn't delimited correctly for CSS, which uses `|`.

`xn:SubNetwork` isn't correct for XPath either though, as you needed to tell Nokogiri where to look in the document. `//` means "search everywhere" in XPath-ese and would allow Nokogiri to determine it should use XPath:

```
doc.at('//xn:SubNetwork', namespaces)['id'] # => "ONRM_ROOT_MO_R"
```

Read Nokogiri's "[Namespaces](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces)" documentation in the "Searching a XML/HTML Document" tutorial, to the end of the page, along with the [`collect_namespaces`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document:collect_namespaces) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.